# Singular Value Decomposition MIMO

Tags: wireless

Singular Value Decomposition in MIMO Spatial Multiplexing requires knowledge of the channel state information at both the transmit and the receive and allows parallel independent data streams to be transmitted and received.
Question: can different data throughputs be sent on the different parallel channels or data streams?

Answer (score 1):

MIMO Spatial Multiplexing doesn't allow 'parallel independent data streams' as such, it allows more data to be sent than through one connection. For instance, in 4x4 MIMO, a fairly 'clean' channel may allow no increase, or to only 1.5x throughput, depending on conditions. A channel with lots of multipath may allow 2.5x, 3x or possibly even 3.5x throughput. This throughput is received on the entire ensemble of N antennae. The lower the correlation of signals between antennae, the more data can be extracted.

How this throughput is grouped into logical channels running at particular rates is up to the higher levels in the protocol. We already run multiple logical channels of different rates over ordinary single connections anyway, so there's nothing new there

Comment: I agree that spatial multiplexing relies on 2 factors: 1- The rank of the channel matrix and 2- its condition number here is what David Tse in his book: "Fundamentals of Wireless Communications" says about SVD:" There is a clear analogy between this architecture (SVD) and the OFDM system. In both cases, a transformation is applied to convert a matrix channel into a set of parallel independent sub-channels"